# How to remove value from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to remove a particular value from an array. But not able to remove because the array is like this

```
  var cardValue = {
      options: ['Bus', 'Car', 'Motor'],
    };
```

So, How to remove a value for that array?

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter</h1>`;

var cardValue = {
  options: ['Bus', 'Car', 'Motor'],
};

const index = this.cardValue.options.indexOf('Bus');
if (index > -1) {
  this.cardValue.options.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(cardValue); // Car, Motor
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-a1jxhx?file=index.js

Comment: remove `this` when trying to access the `cardValue` object

Comment: Iterate over the objects nested array `cardValue.options.map((val, index)` and compare the value, if there's a match, splice the value using the index `return val === 'Bus' ? cardValue.options.splice(index, 1) : null`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `this` before accessing `cardValue` object

```js
var cardValue = {
  options: ['Bus', 'Car', 'Motor'],
};
    
const index = cardValue.options.indexOf('Bus');
if (index > -1) {
  cardValue.options.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(cardValue); // Car, Motor
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var list = ["bar", "baz", "foo", "qux"];

list.splice(0, 2);

console.log(list);
```

// Starting at index position 0, remove two elements ["bar", "baz"] and retains ["foo", "qux"].